# How to add a custom identifier to a fragment of WordprocessingML

Tags: vsto, wordprocessingml

I'm implementing a Word 2010 VSTO add-in to enable users to edit rich text content in Microsoft Word. The add-in saves the content authored by the uses to a database as WordprocessingML markup. I need to provide the functionality to edit multiple database items in a single Word document. When the user saves the document, the add-in uploads the XML of each item to the database.

The problem I ran into is how to identify which XML fragment belongs to which item. Ideally, what I would like to achieve is something similar to a `div` element in HTML with which I could wrap each item and add a custom identifier to each `div`. Then after the document is saved I could get each div and extract it's inner XML.

Unfortunately, the best solution I currently found is to use bookmarks to mark the start and end of each item in the document. However, this seems to be difficult to implement, since I would have to parse the document for each item, find the start and end bookmark, extract all sibling XML nodes and then make sure that all XML elements are properly closed (since the start and end bookmark can be on different levels in the XML document). This seems quite complex and error prone.

I was wondering if anyone had a similar problem and knows any better solution for it?

Comment: did you tried content controls?

Comment: Yes, I'm already using custom control. Custom XML part binding works great for simple values and for rich text I use a rich text control and retrieve the markup value using code.